# How can I initialize lexical variables in a Perl while condition?

Tags: perl, scope

What is the proper way to write something equivalent to the follow:

```
while ( my $first = $iterator->next && my $second = $iterator->next ) {
  # do work
}
```

This does not run - I wanted `$first` and `$second` in proper scope inside the `while` loop.

Comment: You didn't say what you're trying to do. If your goal is to pull two items from an iterator at once, exiting the loop if there are not at least two items remaining in it or if one of the items has a false value, this will work fine and your variables `$first` and `$second` will have the proper scope.

Comment: Are you doing it with && to catch the end of the iterator?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want parentheses around the assignment expressions.

```
while ((my $first = $iterator->next) && (my $second = $iterator->next)) {
   # ...
}
```

`&&` has higher precedence than `=`, so your original code looked like it was trying to do an assignment like  `x && y = z`.

Comment: Ah, I thought I was doing it plain wrong, but just a silly mistake.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This is where `and` would be more appropriate than `&&`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $it = make_iterator();

while ( my $first = $it->() and my $second = $it->() ) {
    print "$first\t$second\n";
}

sub make_iterator {
    my @x = qw(a b c);
    return sub {
        return shift(@x) if @x;
        return;
    };
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> it
a       b
```

I would be tempted to take the assignment to `$second` out of the `while` (depends on the meaning of the iterator not returning an even number of elements):

```
while ( my $first = $it->() ) {
    defined(my $second = $it->())
        or warn "Iterator returned odd number of elements\n"
        and last;
    print "$first\t$second\n";
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> it
a       b
Iterator returned odd number of elements
```

Answer (score 8):

I tend to write something like that as:

```
 while( my( $first, $second ) = map { ... } 1..2 ) {
      ...
      }
```

You may not like that syntax because you aren't used to doing things that way, but it follows a couple rules that I think make code easier:

- I don't type the same thing twice
- I assign to all the variables at once
- I use the map to generate the list when I need to run something more than once.
- I don't use logical operators gratuitously.

However, there's another problem. You have to figure out what you are really testing in the `while` condition, and make that apparent to the next programmer. I'm not sure why you have two things in that condition. Is it okay to read the iterator if there is only one thing (i.e. what happens to the unprocessed odd man out)?

A much better solution would be some way that you show what you are trying to do without showing the mechanics. Not knowing anything about your iterator, I might suggest that you decorate it with another method that returns two items (or maybe the empty list if it is at the end):

```
 while( my( $first, $second ) = $iterator->read_two ) {
      ...;
      }
```

If that doesn't make the situation clear, decorate it with a method to ask a particular question:

```
 while( $iterator->two_things_left ) {
      my( $first, $second ) = $iterator->read_two;
      ...;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
my $first;
my $second;
while (($first = $iterator->next) && ($second = $iterator->next)) {
  # do work
}
```

Comment: Why? That is, if `$first` and `$second` are simply loop variables, why give them broader scope?

Comment: @Telemachus: Tried `while(my ($a,$b) = (1,1))` then this, but yeah mobrule's answer is better (I voted for it) :)